# Automatically force update pom to newer versions from inside a test

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-versions-plugin

This is not related to update the pom dependencies using a maven goal. I already have that sorted out.
So I am responsible for creating, packaging and maintaining common utilities. These common utilities are in turn used by all the teams in the org. Problem is that the teams using these utilities do not update the dependencies unless it is the last resort. We would like them to use the latest release version of our common utilities barring very few.
Now I have come across this [Maven Versions Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) by mojohaus which I think serves my need by using two goals - `versions:update-properties` and `versions:use-latest-releases`. It serves my purpose except two things:

1. I do not see a way to exclude certain groupid:artifactid from the update dependency/property
2. We really want this to be a compulsory thing (maybe part of the Test execution - this is for test automation utilities mainly) rather than a maven goal. Because if it is a maven goal, it needs to be invoked separately and hence becomes optional for teams.

We know that forcefully updating to latest version might cause some issues with defect re-produciblity, but we are willing to take that risk. Our utilities are really test products.

Any direction/help on this is appreciated.

Edit: We run our tests using maven goals `clean install` already. So they use existing pom. We want dependencies update to happen before the tests run. Also it is desirable to commit the changes to source control (bitbucket) if possible.
We have our tests setup using Jenkins but teams also run multiple test on local machines.

Edit: Found the answer to #1. The plugin provides to exlude regex for group and artifact id. using tags `excludes` and `excludesList`

Comment: First I would automate this via CI solution like Jenkins...You should read the [docs](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html)

Comment: If you do not care about reproducibility, why not use SNAPSHOT versions?

Comment: @khmarbaise - updated the description. We are already using Jenkins but teams also run tests locally. We would like them to use the latest versions of utilities for multiple reasons both from Jenkins and Local. Now we can control Jenkins because all the tests are following a template.

Comment: @JF Meier - Maven Versions Plugin also updates all the other dependencies in the pom and the SNAPSHOTS might still be buggy from third party deps.

Comment: @ashkaps Could you tell me why it is a problem when the teams do not update their dependencies? If they are happy with the old ones, why not let them keep the old ones?

Comment: @JF Meier - We frequently roll-out new updates to the common utilities that makes the execution faster/bug fixes/enhancements and some features that help us with execution and data capturing.

Comment: But if the developers are happy with the old one, why force them? We have utilities jars in our company that are used in various different versions at the same time.

Comment: I think I have already answered that. It’s a decision and now i am trying to find the best possible way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for insisting. From the Maven point of view I see two main solutions:

1. Your projects and your utility jar are tightly coupled and every project always needs to use the latest version. Then you can bundle all projects and your utility in one multi-module project. This makes sure that everything is up to date all the time, but it requires that all projects and your utilities are always build together (not separately).
2. You distribute your utilities to different projects which build and release at different times. Then it is up to the projects to decide when to update. There is unfortunately no standard way to deprecate jars.

If I understand you correctly, you want something "in the middle". This may be hard to achieve.